# PIR sensor amplifier with minimum component count

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, comparator, instrumentation-amplifier, pir

I'm new to opamps and I could use some help amplifying a PIR sensor and output to a microcontroller.

Minimum component count without compromising performance (highly integrated solutions).

Here is a provisional circuit I drew:

[image]

It uses a instrumentation amplifier as pre-amp and a duel comparator for window detector.

I know people usually use quad general purpose opamp (1 pre-amp, 2 comparator, 1 post-amp) for this but they require loads of external components.

- Q1 is IRA-S210ST01.
- Does Ref pin need buffering ? perhaps a unity-gain amp ? but it would increase component count.

**Any comment is greatly appreciated !**

Update:
[image]

added ref buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The typical input resistance of the REF pin is given as 20k. The external resistance connected to this pin is 200k (R4+R5). This means that the net resistance across the REF pin will be 18.2k which means the reference voltage will shift.

So, you should either

- buffer the reference voltage, or
- decrease the divider resistors.

The first option will increase the total power consumption and can be a bit problematic if your circuit will be supplied from a battery. The other option will increase the complexity.

Comment: Thanks for the comment on the ref buffer. Could you please comment on the comparator part as well ?

Comment: @7E10FC9A The input bias current of LT1720 can be as low as -6uA. This may cause the voltages of dividers to shift. Maybe you should decrease the divider resistors. I personally suggest you build the circuit, perform test and measurements, and fine tune if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove R6 and R7 that slow down and alter ADC conversions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment ! LTC1720 has CMOS output, I'm thinking about replacing ADC with digital I/O, is an AND gate necessary ?

Comment: Exactly. Connect that digital output to an interrupt input pin of your microcontroller so that the microcontroller can be woken up on event.